# Plot the time axis with milliseconds in Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using flot library to plot the graph , i am able to plot only up to seconds using this

```
xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S"
        }
```

I want to also plot milliseconds on x-axis . Is it possible ?
Any help / suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no, you would have to provide your own tickFormatter, like this:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    tickFormatter: function(value, axis) {
        return value % 1000;
    }
}
```

We really should add a format specifier for that, though; perhaps %f, like Python.  You should definitely open an [enhancement issue](https://github.com/flot/flot/issues) for this on Github.

Comment: I tried with this it shows only milliseconds but is any way where i can incorporate like in this form hour:minutes:seconds:milliseconds .....May be i am not getting you correctly.... any ways thnxs for ur support !!

Comment: Sure; you just need to add additional modulos, i.e. (value / 1000) % 60 will give you seconds.  Basically you need to build the string yourself.  I'm unsure why you need hours and minutes, though, if you're using millisecond precision.  If your axis really goes from, i.e. 200ms to 4200ms, then the hours and minutes will never change.  Yet if the range is wider, then the milliseconds will naturally be zero at all ticks.